# When testing at Cypress, the memory runs out

Tags: google-chrome, cypress

After migrating the server to another machine, I get cypress tests crash on lack of memory, see picture. I have set the parameter "numTestsKeptInMemory": 0 .

I use Chrome browser for tests. Does anyone know how to adjust the memory?

[image]

I have it all in a cypress.json file:

```
"testFiles": [
    "01_Settings/KeyMateOnline/settings.js",
    "GRP_1000_Groups and SiteCollections/TC_5.0_GRP_1002_CreateNewGroup.js",
    "GRP_1000_SGroups and SiteCollections/TC_5.0_GRP_1003_Creating a new SiteCollection.js",
    "SNP_0800_Snapshots/TC_5.0_SNP_0801_Manual Snapshot Creation.js",
    "REP_0500_Reporting Functions/REP_1_Permissions by User/TC_5.0_REP_1_0501_Filter by Role.js",
    "REP_0500_Reporting Functions/REP_1_Permissions by User/TC_5.0_REP_1_0502_Filter by Member.js",
    "REP_0500_Reporting Functions/REP_2_Permissions by Role/TC_5.0_REP_2_0504_Filter by Role.js",
    "REP_0500_Reporting Functions/REP_2_Role-based Permissions/TC_5.0_REP_2_0505_Filter by Member.js",
    "REP_0500_Reporting Functions/REP_3_Membership by Role/TC_5.0_REP_3_0506_Filter Membership by Role.js",
    "REP_0500_Reportovací funkce/REP_4_Sdílení/TC_5.0_REP_4_0509_Filtr Sdílení.js",
    "EXE_0600_Execution Function/EXE_1_Group Membership/TC_5.0_EXE_1_0600_Adding Selected User to SP Group.js",
    "SNP_0800_Snapshots/TC_5.0_SNP_0800_Smazání Snapshotu.js",
    "SNP_0800_Snapshots/TC_5.0_SNP_0801_Manually create Snapshot.js",
    "EXE_0600_Execution Functions/EXE_1_Group Membership/TC_5.0_EXE_1_0602_Removing selected user from SP group.js",
    "SNP_0800_Snapshots/TC_5.0_SNP_0800_Smazání Snapshotu.js",
    "SNP_0800_Snapshots/TC_5.0_SNP_0801_Manual creation of Snapshot.js",
    "EXE_0600_Execution Functions/EXE_2_Permissions/TC_5.0_EXE_2_0601_Assign permissions to specific selected users.js",
    "SNP_0800_Snapshots/TC_5.0_SNP_0800_Smazání Snapshotu.js",
    "SNP_0800_Snapshots/TC_5.0_SNP_0801_Manual creation of Snapshot.js",
    "EXE_0600_Execution Functions/EXE_2_Permissions/TC_5.0_EXE_2_0603_Removing permissions for specific selected users.js",
    "SNP_0800_Snapshots/TC_5.0_SNP_0803_Creating Exception from Snapshots.js",
    "SNP_0800_Snapshots/TC_5.1_SNP_0804_View and delete Snapshots exception.js",
    "NTF_1100_Notifications/TC_5.1_NTF_1100_Creating a new notification for a specific site.js",
    "NTF_1100_Notifications/TC_5.1_NTF_1101_Display Notification Overview.js",
    "MSP_1200_Multisnapshot/TC_5.1_MSP_1200_Creating a report in the main Site collection container.js",
    "GRP_1000_SGroups and SiteCollections/TC_5.0_GRP_1008/Delete Site Collection.js"
  ],

...
```

Comment: How many tests do you have in the file that crashes during the run?

Comment: I have 26 test there.

Comment: That could be the reason why it is crashing. You may want to break them down into more spec files.

Comment: I've added it to the specification as I have it in the cypress.json file. Do you know how to split it so that I can run it all in the result? I'm rather surprised that it worked before with the same number of tests.

Comment: Depending on the amount if steps for each test you can have each broken down file to run 3 or so.